# Adding tag and ranking metaData to an image in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, exif, alassetslibrary

How can I add a custom ranking and keywords to an image's `metaData` in objective-c? 
I have seen `CGImageProperties_` [reference in apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html) but it does not have any key for the ranking and tagging.

Comment: There is no standard I know of. Create your own values but they will only be of value to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather create my own class with CGImage inside and equipped with ranking and metadata dictionary